# SAP Connector 3.x - IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS - How to get the response status code - .Net

Tags: .net, sap-dotnet-connector, idoc

I'm pushing IDOCs through the SAP .NET Connector 3.x from .NET.
For doing this I'm using the `IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS` function.

Is there a way to get the response status code of the IDOC push?
I'm expecting something like this:

Inbound status of an IDoc

> 50     IDoc added
>
> 51     Application document not posted
>
> 52     Application document not fully posted
>
> 53     Application document posted
>
> 54     Error during formal application check
>
> 55     Formal application check OK
>
> 56     IDoc with errors added
>
> 57     Test IDoc: Error during application check
>
> ...

Thanks!

Comment: I can't check it right now, but if you can get the idoc number from the function module (the FM may update the table parameters you submitted with the idoc number), you can then use function module RFC_READ_TABLE to read table EDIDS and retrieve the status codes for this idoc.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks! When i look into the function i hvae created after the invoke I don't see any IDOC number:
{FUNCTION IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS (TABLES PARAMETER IDOC_CONTROL_REC_40=TABLE  [STRUCTURE EDI_DC40 { FIELD TABNAM=EDI_DC40 FIELD MANDT= FIELD DOCNUM= FIELD DOCREL= FIELD STATUS=....

Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: maybe not. Could be that you just don't get the idoc number from the FM. A somewhat ugly hack would be to look for your idoc in the idoc tables (IDIDC, IDID4 etc.) after submitting it. Depending on the idoc traffic that can work ranging from "very well" to "catastrophicly bad". But if you search in a narrow timeframe that may be a quick solution.